# Will the console window close after the main thread have done his work if there are some foreground threads that print something on the console?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console-application

Will the console window close after the main thread have done his work if there are some foreground threads that print something on the console? So basically will text that is printed in other threads be shown on the console?

Something like the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("string");

            var threads = new Thread[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; ++i)
            {
                threads[i] = new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine("smth"));
                threads[i].Start();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: @HenkHolterman console didn't close, text from other threads was printed

Comment: You can add a Thread.Sleep() to the lambda to make it more convincing.

Comment: A definitive statement from the documentation is of course preferable. But you already use the term 'foreground'. Either there, or in the definiton of background, will be your specification.

Comment: @HenkHolterman ok, thank you

Comment: Note that you use a sync "for" loop, and the method `new Thread` itself takes time to execute. So what you observed can be imperfect from what you really want.

Comment: @LexLi I added Thread.Sleep(10000) to the lambda to make it more indicative

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you run the code (.NET Framework, .NET Core, or Mono) you should adjust the sleep time.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("string");

    var threads = new Thread[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = new Thread(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("smth");
        }) { IsBackground = true };
        threads[i].Start();
    }
}
```